# decode / encode base64 perl

Tags: perl, encoding, base64, decoding

People on stackoverflow helped me with a base64 decoding in Perl but I would like to have the script in reverse :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Base64;

my $str = 'CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg';

my @chars = split //, decode_base64 $str;
my @codes = map ord, @chars;
print "@codes\n";
```

Output = 9 45 180 82 233 134 21 164 166 209 5 217 231 129 192 14

Now I would like to have the output as my `$str` and `CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg` as output?
I've been trying it for some hours but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: i would like to have CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg as an output, so basicly the opposite of how i have it right now. Is that possible??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`chr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html) as the inverse of [`ord`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Base64;

my @array = qw(9 45 180 82 233 134 21 164 166 209 5 217 231 129 192 14);

my $str = encode_base64(join '', map chr, @array);

print $str, "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg==
```

This is stated in perldoc (emphasis mine):

> - `ord EXPR`
> - `ord`
>
>   Returns the numeric value of the first character of `EXPR`. If `EXPR` is an empty string, returns `0`. If `EXPR` is omitted, uses `$_`. (Note *character*, not byte.)
>
>   **For the reverse**, see [`chr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html). See [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) for more about Unicode.

Comment: thanks @Miller appreciate your help but is it maybe possible to print without the == at the end of the string, so that i get 22 characters??

Comment: I suspect that it will NOT be possible to reverse this action without the ending `==`.  If you start with this string you will see that the codes result is the same `my @codes = map ord, split //, decode_base64 "CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg==";`.  So this has something to do with `MIME::Base64`, and you'll have to investigate/debug  this issue separately.

Comment: is it possible to randomize the numbers so i can generate automaticly different output for the array? my @array = qw(9 45 180 82 233 134 21 164 166 209 5 217 231 129 192 14); so call different numbers in the array??

Answer (score 1):

```
use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 );

my $str = encode_base64 pack 'C*', @codes;
```

That will get you the base64 encoding, `CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg==`. To get `CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg` (which is not valid base64), you'll need to remove the trailing `=` characters afterwards.

```
$str =~ s/=+\z//;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to use encode_base64url instead, which uses _ and - instead of / and + and omits the trailing =.

Comment: is it possible to randomize the numbers so i can generate automaticly different output for the array? my array = qw(9 45 180 82 233 134 21 164 166 209 5 217 231 129 192 14); so call different numbers in the array??

Comment: randomize which numbers?  I don't understand what you are asking; try asking a new question showing example input and output.

Comment: use MIME::Base64;
my array = qw(9 45 180 82 233 134 21 164 166 209 5 217 231 129 192 14);
my $str = encode_base64(join '', map chr, array); 
im trying to change the numbers so that the output changes everytime when i run the script. now the output = CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg== so i want to randomly change that with the change of the number @ysth

Comment: really, you should create a new question.  *why* do you want the output to be different?  should the original numbers have anything to do with the output?